# Scrollable div with nowrap and hidden scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal menu which consists of a parent div with `overflow:hidden` and a child with `overflow:auto`. This allows me to have a scrollable div with no scrollbar. 
However, to prevent a break in the li elements, the child element has a `white-space:nowrap` attribute. This makes the scrollbar appear again. 
I tried using a `display:table` as an alternative to the nowrap but that doesn't allow scrolling.
Any ideas on how to proceed?
Thanks

UPDATE:
Seeing as I have not been able to explain myself correctly, I have uploaded a small example of what I want on jsfiddle: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/6bmu7m0k/)
I want a list of items next to each other which is wider than container and for the user to be able to scroll but without the scrollbar showing. If I have the `white-space:nowrap` attribute, the scrollbar is present but if I remove it, the elements will go under each other.
Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

#scroller {
    width: 270px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
        foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>
```

> Try This One For E.g

Comment: Maybe I explained myself incorrectly. I want a horizontal menu so each element should be next to each other, no line breaks. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Sorry Than i m not sure clear requirement check this link i think it will work [Link](http://www.kaizou.org/2013/02/different-ways-of-arranging)

Comment: @Umang Patwa is it possible to do the same thing but for a horizontal  scrollbar? I would like to implement this, but the horizontal scrolling is not working...